# use .ts object as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a little trouble with the syntax on passing some object info as props for my component. I got this .ts file with an export const called producte and it's just an array with some objects, but instead of render it on a component i would like to use this info as props (cause there will be parfum2, 3 ...)
what am i missing here?

```
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "../src/NavBar";
import ProductPage from "../src/ProductPage";
import { producte } from "../data/producte";
    
const parf1= () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <ProductPage name={producte.title} />
    </>
  );
};

export default parf1;
```

the product:

```
export const producte = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Oceanic Pearl",
    price: 400,
    description:
      "Donec eleifend ligula et nisi pellentesque pharetra. Fusce vestibulum tortor sit amet lectus dignissim, in sodales augue semper. Sed tincidunt lorem ex, ut semper orci ornare odales. Vivamus nec ex in tortor aliquet dapibus eget in justo. Vivamus sollicitudin sapien eget dictum accumsan. Etiam pellentesque, justo ac tincidunt elementum, velit ex vulputate purus, ac luctus velit sem nec eros. Nam at nisl non lectus egestas cursus mollis sit amet nisl.",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Montmartre's Pride",
    price: 420,
    description:
      "Vivamus sollicitudin sapien eget dictum accumsan. Etiam pellentesque, justo ac tincidunt elementum, velit ex vulputate purus, ac luctus velit sem nec eros. Nam at nisl non lectus egestas cursus mollis sit amet nisl. In tortor aliquet dapibus eget in justo.",
  },
];
```

Comment: Is the code you are showing in a JS file or TS file...?

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(producte)`? (Or inspect it in a debugger, the important part is checking its value)

Comment: it's a tsx file and if i log it i get the right values (my object info)

Comment: Firsty - parf1 should begin with a capital letter if its intended as a React components. Secondly show the code for producte.ts. I'm assuming this is the props you are importing.

Answer (score 1):

To derive the type of one of the products in your array, you can use this syntax:

```ts
typeof producte[number]
```

This means: a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#unions) of the [inferred](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#handbook-content) type of each element in the `producte` array.

Here's a more complete example demonstrating how to use it:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxgTzAUzgJTQQwMYwCiANmiGgHYwC+cAZlBCHAORS4EsDcAUDwCZo8xHO3oBXCgWAQKcAAqN+4gvJwBzDAAowjMAGcAXIjgUc5Y-phRgFdXGoBKY9nxFS5Krx55ZVuLoQygQYALxwANo8cIjRMXDA-MYAjAA0cTEwwDCkxgBEAPJ4uBTAeAq4UMR56fEBNsXGACwADC218YL6eDZgWbKGGfF5ACKyQnBopMB0lPxwxMDq4iKT8KX6wAFTpFRo+gCO4hhgABaiaNY4AHRwAGLi3RgAbvtZAEYr4sww0L9QcE28HMlwWQhgjzg-CWG02IFSCTk+iCOFI+jgOHEyww+jI6CgtwAymh5lkpIlJPBiNAyJMAB4I8TwXHgNAA6B4LbQMxiFFo24ANWAz3MkIoEzQdMRcH+-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)

```ts
import {type ReactElement} from 'react';

declare function ProductPage (props: { name: string }): ReactElement;

const producte = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Oceanic Pearl",
    price: 400,
    description:
      "Donec eleifend ligula et nisi pellentesque pharetra. Fusce vestibulum tortor sit amet lectus dignissim, in sodales augue semper. Sed tincidunt lorem ex, ut semper orci ornare odales. Vivamus nec ex in tortor aliquet dapibus eget in justo. Vivamus sollicitudin sapien eget dictum accumsan. Etiam pellentesque, justo ac tincidunt elementum, velit ex vulputate purus, ac luctus velit sem nec eros. Nam at nisl non lectus egestas cursus mollis sit amet nisl.",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Montmartre's Pride",
    price: 420,
    description:
      "Vivamus sollicitudin sapien eget dictum accumsan. Etiam pellentesque, justo ac tincidunt elementum, velit ex vulputate purus, ac luctus velit sem nec eros. Nam at nisl non lectus egestas cursus mollis sit amet nisl. In tortor aliquet dapibus eget in justo.",
  },
];

type Product = typeof producte[number];
    
const Parf1 = (props: { product: Product }): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* <NavBar /> */}
      <ProductPage name={props.product.title} />
    </>
  );
};

// Use: Map each product data to its own component:
producte.map(product => (<Parf1 product={product} />))
```